# 80s British comic story where flying jellyfish suck people's faces off

Tags: story-identification, comics

When I was about 5 or so (early 80s) my brother bought a comic from a local newsagent. It was black and white (cover possibly in color) and I remember it was a story, set on Earth, it had an invasion of flying jellyfish like creatures that sucked people's faces off (I remember one comic panel where a General/Brigadier or similar British military type gets killed by one and it reveals his skull as it pulls his face off). I think the protagonists were a man and a woman who seemed to be scientists. The art style I think was your general 80s Dan Dare style.

Anyway, this gave me nightmares at the time, but I'm morbidly curious to find the comic again. For a long time I thought it was 2000AD, but after many years looking through it, I'm under the impression it possibly wasn't 2000AD after all. But I don't remember many other publically available comics along that line.

UPDATE - Possibly Dan Dare or Eagle - someone else seems to recall the story on this thread here: [2000ad thread](https://forums.2000ad.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=dlukmef7p0hsepo7ptk56ta2na&topic=45150.msg981614#msg981614)

Comment: Sounds like something from the great tradition of inappropriately violent classic British comics! The best I could do on Google was 'Invasion 1984', published in Battle - but the aliens in this are skeletons rather than jellyfish. Maybe something from Dr Who magazine?

Comment: The time period is also right for Starblazer; definitely seems like a story they might have published.

Comment: It looks like it might have been Dan Dare?? Or a story published by Eagle? I found this comment which roughly confirms the story I was thinking of?

[forum thread on 2000ad](https://forums.2000ad.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=dlukmef7p0hsepo7ptk56ta2na&topic=45150.msg981614#msg981614)

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question,  if you think you have it.

Comment: Sadly @Spencer I still don't know the comic story or have not encountered any panels online that identify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it was definitely Dan Dare. I remember the cover here. Issues [167 to 169](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/eagle-169/4000-302427/) of New Eagle Comic:

[image]

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons.